# How can I fix this code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, web

This code does not work as expected and I don't know what's wrong.

szTeam should change, but doesn't.

Could anyone explain this?

```
-----------------------------------------------------

WCHAR   szTeam[MAX_PATH] = L"\u7F57\u5207\u8FBE\u5C14\u6D41\u6D6A";
char    szMsg[MAX_PATH];

sprintf(szMsg , "%s"  , WideStringToMultiByte(szTeam));
swprintf( szTeam , L"%s" , MultiByteToWideString(szMsg));

......

WCHAR* MultiByteToWideString(const char* szSrc)
{
    int iSizeOfStr = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szSrc, -1, NULL, 0);  
    wchar_t* wszTgt = new wchar_t[iSizeOfStr];  
    if(!wszTgt)
        return (NULL);  
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szSrc, -1, wszTgt, iSizeOfStr);
    return(wszTgt);
}

char* WideStringToMultiByte(const wchar_t* wszSrc)  
{  
    int iSizeOfStr = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wszSrc, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);  
    char* szTgt = new char[iSizeOfStr];  
    if(!szTgt)
        return(NULL);  
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wszSrc, -1, szTgt, iSizeOfStr, NULL, NULL);  
    return szTgt;    
} 

-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem? I see a few issues there

Comment: You're taking a wide character string, convert it to a multibyte character string, and the convert it back. And you you say that the result after that is the same as what you started with?

Comment: put input output and what do you expect to get..

Comment: I want to convert Unicode Hex to String.

Comment: @bTagTiger What do you mean by 'Unicode Hex'? `\uXXXX` notation in string literal? You don't have to convert it, compiler does it for you, generating correct string.

Comment: @bTagTiger Also note about NULL checks in functions - they are obsolete since VS2003, `new` statement will not return NULL but throw exception in case of problems (according to C++ standard). And of course you have to delete memory returned from `WideStringToMultiByte/MultiByteToWideString` - or better use some kind of smart pointers.

Comment: Well, it doesn't convert correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, no szTeam *does* change.  Into something unrecognizable, mojibake.  You start out with "罗切达尔流浪" and convert it from its utf-16 encoding to utf-8.  That works fine.  The debugger won't show you anything recognizable because it neither knows nor cares that szMsg is encoded in utf-8.

You then go wrong though, you are converting that utf-8 string with CP_ACP.  Which says that the string is encoded in the default system code page.  It is not, it was encoded in utf-8.

Fix your problem with:

```
WCHAR* MultiByteToWideString(const char* szSrc)
{
    int iSizeOfStr = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, szSrc, -1, NULL, 0);  
    // etc..
}
```

And now szTeam *won't* change because the string got properly converted back.